# Enter key not detected with Tkinter (using python 3)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm tring to make a console app, so I want to detect when the user uses the "Enter" key, but it doesn't call my function when it's supposed to be.. Here's the code

```
CommandBar = Text(WINDOW, height="500", width="1000", bg="Black", fg="green", insertbackground="green")


WINDOW.geometry("1000x500")
WINDOW.title("SCP_OS:/Unknown User*")
WINDOW.configure(bg="black")



def ResetCommandBar(CommandEntered):
    CommandBar.insert(END, "SCP_OS:/Unkown_User : ")
    print(123)

WINDOW.bind("<Enter>", ResetCommandBar(CommandBar.get("1.0", "end -1c")))

CommandBar.pack()

WINDOW.mainloop()
```

Comment: there isn't any prints of "123"

Comment: Change `ResetCommandBar(...)` to `lambda e: ResetCommandBar()`. Also the binding for the enter key is "<Return>"`, not `"<Enter>"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Button's command executed immediately when I create the Button, and not when I click it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-my-buttons-command-executed-immediately-when-i-create-the-button-and-no) It's not exactly the same but still the same mistake and same solution.

Comment: "<Enter>" to "<Text>"